What does "Maybe we can put the whole thing off on a few big shots" mean?
In the movie "Chinatown" by Roman Polanski there is a scene in which Jack Nicholson's character accuses a local municipal government official about murder and dumping out of local reservoirs during drought. He doesn't know if the official did it himself or he was payed off by someone who benefited from the situation. He gives him an ultimatum.
"I don't want to nail you. I want to find out who put you up to it. Call me I can help. Who knows? Maybe we can put the whole thing off on a few big shots and you can stay the head of the department for the next few years."
I know that "put it on someone" means to "blame someone for something" but he clearly says "put it off".
I don't know any sense of the phrasal verb "put off" that would fit this context.

Put something off on somebody: ascribe it to them.

This is an example of 'prepositional padding'. Sometimes English speakers include unnecessary prepositions in their speech, for example, "where are you at?" does not need the word 'at'; "he jumped off of the table" does not require the word 'of'. It's more common to hear this in conversation than in professional writing, but that doesn't mean that it is wrong. Although not entirely necessary, the extra prepositions can sometimes add value. For example, "where are you" might be used when you have absolutely no idea of a person's whereabouts, while "where are you at" might suggest that you know the person is going somewhere and you want to know if they have arrived 'at' their destination, or where along the journey they are.
I checked the original shooting script for the movie and it actually had the line "Maybe we can lay the whole thing off on a few big shots" (sometimes actors or directors make last-minute changes to shooting scripts). To put something on or to lay something on something or someone means to ascribe it to them - in the context of your quotation, it specifically means to lay the blame on them (perhaps unfairly). The phrase does not need the preposition "off" - it is entirely superfluous. It may have been included in the script to make the dialogue sound more colloquial or extemporaneous. But it could arguably add some meaning - simply putting blame "on" someone means you've ascribed the blame to them, while putting blame "off onto" them means the blame is coming 'off' one person and 'on' to another.

Can also be understood as emphasizing "off [of you and] on[to]" someone else.

@AndyBonner Good point, I've updated my answer.

off there has the figurative sense of putting some "distance" between us and the problem. Get it "away" from us (and onto somebody else).
Compare:

They saw their friend off at the pier.
The car drove off.
I didn't want to deal with it, so I kept putting it off.
Be off with you, you damn kids. Stop banging on my door!

There's also the expression "to palm something off as [something desirable]".  It means to represent it as being valuable in order to dupe someone and thereby get rid of it at a profit.

That fake is really good, Bobby boy. We could palm it off as an authentic Jackson Pollock and make a killing.


Maybe we can put the whole thing off on a few big shots .....
" a few big shots " persons or an organization with a lot of power or influence.
he is saying maybe  "the big shots" will get the blame or take the fall for the crime.
